# How to calculate jamFactor?

Tags: here-api

- For routing api v7, jamFactor was returned as a part of dynamicSpeedinfo.
- In new routing api v8, jamFactor is removed.
- Documentation says, jamFactor can be calculated easily by user from base speed and traffic speed for a given segment in dynamicSpeedinfo.

**What is the logic for computing the jamFactor ?**

I am unable to find that from the documentations !

Answer (score 0):

The extended documentation of the HERE SDK (that also uses v8 routing for the route requests) explains a few more details that might help:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate/4.13.4.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#find-traffic-along-a-route

It says:

> Note that the jamFactor indicating TrafficSpeed is calculated linear
> from the ratio of trafficSpeedInMetersPerSecond /
> baseSpeedInMetersPerSecond - without taking road types and other
> parameters into account. Therefore, the provided jamFactor does not
> necessarily match exactly the traffic flow visualization on the map
> view (if enabled).

And shows a possible mapping for the calculated factors then as well.